# Icon is to small in native splash screen under 12

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, native, splash-screen

I am little lost here. I am implementing the splash screen system in my app. I am using the new api where we really are implementing the native splash screen in android.

1:In emulator api 31 when the app start for the first time from the Android Studio all the screen is the color that I selected but no icon. But when I close the app and open again from the emulator works fine.
2:Under 12 I change the color just to see if is correctly and ok but the icon is very small.

My lauch_background.xml from drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/branding"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Inside this folder there are a background.png that is the color that I selected and the lauch_background...

Where this small icon is coming from? How can I change the size?

But in the others api like 32 or 34 the icon have the correct size.

An the must strange. My real smarthphone is a 11 android version and the splash screen have the color that I had set to apis lower than 12 but have Brand image!?!? Brand image isnt a new function from 12?

Thank you

Comment: One issue have an answer: TL;DR kill the app and run from the launcher, icon does not show up when run from Android Studio. From Joseph Hawkes-Cates

Comment: ok, the problem is that I was using the same image in pubspec settings. So I choose to a bigger image